# How to auto center Google Maps API with multiple KML files

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having an issue where I am loading multiple klm files in to google maps. I want map to auto zoom and center so that all klm files are shown and zoomed appropriately. It does it on its own with a single klm file loaded, however if a second one is loaded, it auto zooms and centers only to the second klm. The first one is there, but need to navigate the map to see it. Here is the code I am working with

```
<script>
var map = null;
var layers = [];
var infowindow;
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(300, 0),
    });
    function showInContentWindow(kmlEvent) {
        var content = "<div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.description + "</div>";
        infowindow.setPosition(kmlEvent.latLng);
        infowindow.setOptions({
        pixelOffset:kmlEvent.pixelOffset,
        content: content});
        infowindow.open(map);
    }

    layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Rocky-Gap-Trail.kmz',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "click", showInContentWindow);

    layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Angel-Peak.kmz',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "click", showInContentWindow);

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    }

}


function toggleLayer(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDdhhhuGjK30fC4XyVauWELrgBFbXJ5Iq8&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the DefaultViewport of each layer (once is has been set), then zoom the map to the union of all the layers.

```
var bounds;
layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Rocky-Gap-Trail.kmz',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: true,
    map: map
});
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "defaultviewport_changed", function() {
  if (!bounds) {
    bounds = layers[0].getDefaultViewport();
  } else {
    bounds.union(layers[0].getDefaultViewport());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "click", showInContentWindow);

layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Angel-Peak.kmz',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: true,
    map: map
});
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "defaultviewport_changed", function() {
  if (!bounds) {
    bounds = layers[1].getDefaultViewport();
  } else {
    bounds.union(layers[1].getDefaultViewport());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "click", showInContentWindow);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9qzdkxj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var layers = [];
var infowindow;
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(300, 0),
    });
    function showInContentWindow(kmlEvent) {
        var content = "<div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.description + "</div>";
        infowindow.setPosition(kmlEvent.latLng);
        infowindow.setOptions({
        pixelOffset:kmlEvent.pixelOffset,
        content: content});
        infowindow.open(map);
    }
    var bounds;
    layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Rocky-Gap-Trail.kmz',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "defaultviewport_changed", function() {
      if (!bounds) {
        bounds = layers[0].getDefaultViewport();
      } else {
        bounds.union(layers[0].getDefaultViewport());
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[0], "click", showInContentWindow);

    layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.lasvegasjeeptrails.com/kmz/Angel-Peak.kmz',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "defaultviewport_changed", function() {
      if (!bounds) {
        bounds = layers[1].getDefaultViewport();
      } else {
        bounds.union(layers[1].getDefaultViewport());
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layers[1], "click", showInContentWindow);

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    }

}


function toggleLayer(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```